# BuildFire : In ios 10 and 11 Need to tap twice in order for a Click to work

Tags: buildfire

I’m facing a problem with my own developed plugin.

In fact, i developed a plugin using ionic, angularjs 1 and integrate it in a buildfire application. It’s working perfectly in android and in iOS versions that are below iOS 10.

The problem is that i need to tap twice on a link or on a button in order for the click to be executed.

Firstly i thought that this problem is coming from ionic, but once i generated my app as an ionic standalone app and tested it on a physical device all is was working perfectly even in iOS 10 and above.

The problem arise only when my plugin is running in a buildfire environment.

Do you have any idea of what is happening? could you please help me resolving this issue?

Comment: Would it be possible to post the code? That would help quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps.
but Here is my home screen Code:
I'm using ui-sref to navigate between tabs, I tried ng-click but it doesn't work either. please note that everything works correctly on android and on ios versions below 10

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-icon-top tabs-background-royal tabs-color-assertive tabs-fullwidth" tabs-wipable>

  <ion-tab title="Cursuses" icon-off="ion-university" icon-on="ion-university"   ui-sref="app.home.cursus"   >
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-cursus2"></ion-nav-view>


  </ion-tab>


  <ion-tab  title="Soon" icon-off="ion-ios-list-outline"  icon-on="ion-ios-list"   ui-sref="app.home.soon"   >
    <ion-nav-view  name="tab-planning3"></ion-nav-view>

  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```